# Help with anti-image matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

First of all, I am very sorry but I don't know the mathematics terminology in English, so I'll try to explain as good as i can but i will probably do some mistakes since it's not my native language.

I have this problem: given the endomorphism $f_k(x,y,z) = (x+y+kz, x+ky, 2x+(k+1)y+kz)$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, determine for $k \in \mathbb{R}$

1. a base of $\mathop{\rm Im} f_k$ and a base of $\mathop{\rm Ker} f_k$,
2. the set $f^{-1}(0,2,2)$.

I have a good idea on how to solve the first one, but I am blocked on the second one. I'd like some help if possible.

Again, sorry for the many mistakes, and thanks a lot for your patience and attention.

Comment: No need to apologize for the language, I guess. But if you ask a question, it is a good idea to write what you have tried to get more useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition: $f^{-1}(0,2,2) = \{ (x,y,z): f(x,y,z) = (0,2,2) \}$. So, you have a system of equations:

\begin{align*}
0 &= x + y + kz, \\
2 &= x + ky, \\
2 &= 2x + (k+1)y + kz.
\end{align*}

Note that the sum of the first two equations gives you the second, so the system is not regular and will have many solutions or none at all.

I'll assume this is enough of a hint. If you need help with solving the system, feel free to ask in the comments.

**Edit** (solving the system)

I got $x = 2-ky$ from the second equation, and then I substituted $x$ in the first one, obtaining
$$y = \frac{2+kz}{k-1}.$$
Then I've put that in $x = 2-ky$ and got
$$x = -\frac{2+k^2z}{k-1}.$$
[Wolfram|Alpha gives the same solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B0%20=%20x%20%2b%20y%20%2b%20k%2az,%202%20=%20x%20%2b%20k%2ay,%202%20=%202%2ax%20%2b%20%28k%2b1%29%2ay%20%2b%20k%2az%7D,%20%7Bx,y%7D%5D), so it should be correct.

Obviously, for $k = 1$ this solution is not acceptable, as we have a division by zero. This means that we have to solve it separately for $k = 1$ (we could ignore the third equation, as it is still the sum of the first two, but I'll write it anyway):

\begin{align*}
0 &= x + y + z, \\
2 &= x + y, \\
2 &= 2x + 2y + z.
\end{align*}

Now, we have $x = 2 - y$. Putting that into the first equation, we get
$$z = -2.$$
There are no more equations to use, so we're done here.

So, our final solution is:
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(0,2,2) &= \left\{ \left(-\frac{2+k^2z}{k-1}, \frac{2+kz}{k-1}, z \right): z \in \mathbb{R} \right\}, \quad \text{for $k \ne 1$}, \\
f^{-1}(0,2,2) &= \left\{ \left(2 - y, y, -2 \right): y \in \mathbb{R} \right\}, \quad \text{for $k = 1$}.
\end{align*}

We could have solved by $(x,z)$ (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B0%20=%20x%20%2b%20y%20%2b%20k%2az,%202%20=%20x%20%2b%20k%2ay,%202%20=%202%2ax%20%2b%20%28k%2b1%29%2ay%20%2b%20k%2az%7D,%20%7Bx,z%7D%5D)) or by $(y,z)$ (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B0%20=%20x%20%2b%20y%20%2b%20k%2az,%202%20=%20x%20%2b%20k%2ay,%202%20=%202%2ax%20%2b%20%28k%2b1%29%2ay%20%2b%20k%2az%7D,%20%7By,z%7D%5D)), which would give us different parametrizations of the same solution.

To check that these solutions are really correct, try calculating $f(x,y,z)$ of the above parametrized solutions (both cases $k \ne 1$ and $k = 1$). As a result, you should get $(0,2,2)$ in all cases (for all $k$ and $z$).

Comment: Thank you, a question: can I not use the third row since is the sum of the previous two? I'll try to solve it now, if I have problems i will write here :)

Comment: @AscaL Of course you can use it. My remark just means that you will not get a single $(x,y,z)$, but either an empty set (meaning that $(0,2,2)$ is not in $\mathop{\rm Im} f$) or a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $1$ (i.e., something like $\{t(x_0,y_0,z_0):\ t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for some $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$) or $2$ (similar, but a linear combination of two particular not co-linear solutions).

Comment: Ok, so i tried to solve it and what i get is $x=(2+2kz+k^2z)/(k-1)$ and $y = (2-kz)/(k-1)$ does this make any sense? if possible could you show me the steps you did to solve it? Thanks again!

Comment: It's too long, so I'll add it to my answer. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: sure take your time :). Thanks a lot man

Comment: Here. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks man it surely is clear. Have a good night and again thank you!